# Doing .__class__ on various types

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is integer the only type that does not support the `.__class__` operation? for example:

```
>>> ....__class__
<class 'ellipsis'>

>>> 'a'.__class__
<class 'str'>

>>> 2.44.__class__
<class 'float'>

>>> 1.__class__
File "<stdin>", line 1
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 3):

It is supported, but `1.` is parsed as a float literal.

> Is there a way to get around this?

Yes, several ways:

```
(1).__class__
1 .__class__
x = 1; x.__class__
```

Comment: thanks, what would be the difference between a `float` and `float literal` ?

Comment: It also works if you write `1 .__class__` (with a space between `1` and `.`), because the space breaks up the literal, but is ignored for attribute lookup. Of course, in this particular case, the solution is really to just call `type` instead of accessing dunder names at all: `type(1)`.

Comment: Float literal means a floating point value written directly into your source code.